# Azure Service Bus QueueClient RetryPolicy vs Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I would like to know the current best practice for writing a resilient Producer / Consumer using the Service Bus QueueClient.

I'm a little confused over the purpose of the Azure Service Bus QueueClient.RetryPolicy 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.retrypolicy.aspx

and when i should use the Topaz Retry Policy instead
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.transientfaulthandling.retrypolicy.aspx

Does the QueueClient have built in Transient Fault handling and not require the use the Topaz library?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read closer exactly the link you provided for TOPAZ you will see:

> **Retired Content** 
>   This content and the technology described is outdated
>   and is no longer being maintained. For more information, see Transient
>   Fault Handling.

then there a link to the section of [Microsoft Enterprise Library section for Transient Fault Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675232.aspx), which clears it further:

> **Note**:
>
> **Important**: Recent versions of SDKs for both Azure Storage and Azure
>   Service Bus natively support retries. It is recommended to use these
>   instead of the Transient Fault Handling Application Block

So, use the Service Bus SDK built in retry policy.